# Specific transforming rectangle with help CATransform3D or CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, ios, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

Is any way make transforming like at the picture?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ek9.png

**Edit:**

Now, for transformation I use next code:

```
    - (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform {
   transform.m34 = - 0.0004;
   CGFloat clampedOffset = fmaxf(-1.0f, fminf(1.0f, offset));
   CGFloat x = (clampedOffset * 0.5f * _tilt + offset * _spacing) * kWidthView;
   CGFloat z = fabsf(clampedOffset) * - kWidthView * 0.5f;
   transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, x, 0.0f, z);
   return CATransform3DRotate(transform, -clampedOffset * M_PI_2 * _tilt, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining a perspective transformation with a rotation around the y (vertical) axis
and applying that to the view's layer should give that effect, for example:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1.0/200.0;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = transform;
```

Comment: I am tryed this before ask here, but not get wanted result. Thing in that, in this case transforming top and bottom part of view mirrored. Maybe if change center of perspective (transform.m34) result will be expected. Is any way do this?

Comment: @Dickordia: Why did you not tell in your question what you already tried? - I will test this later when I have more time.

Comment: @Dickordia: I have tried this and it seems to work, I cannot recognize a top/view part mirrored. - Perhaps you can show a screenshot demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Now I get something like that: http://imgur.com/Y5zichW But I want get this result: http://i.imgur.com/mHSetAZ

Comment: @Dickordia: Perhaps you should add your code to the question.

Comment: I am probably not seeing something obvious, but the images http://imgur.com/Y5zichW and http://i.imgur.com/mHSetAZ look quite similar to me. Could you perhaps point out what is generally wrong with your result?

Comment: Sory for long time do not answer. Otherness in two variants is angle of transformation  at top and bottom part. Now get this result: http://imgur.com/OkvExj0, wanted will get: http://imgur.com/W2MTgSk, but at now decide use first variant. Thanks for your time and help.